# Parse JSON Object. Extract subkeys

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, object, dictionary

I have a JSON file and want to build a table with 2 columns:

```
{
    "Some name 1": {
        "price": 1023,
        "quantity": 93
    },
    "Some name 2": {
        "price": 2938,
        "quantity": 64
    },
    "Some name 3": {
        "price": 1277,
        "quantity": 211
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/data.json', function (data) {
    for (x in data) {
        document.getElementById(getTDID).innerHTML += x; // First column
        console.log(data[i].price);  // Second column
        console.log(x["quantity"]); // or another variant of second column
    }
}
```

First column works. But second... I want to extract this 2 values (price and quantity), but it doesn't work. So now I haven't ideas. Please help.

Comment: First column does not suppose to work. 'for..in' iterates over the properties of an object, which means `x` will be equal `key<n>` in each iteration. Besides that, you're trying to access `data[i].price` but `i` was never defined.

Comment: That's a typo: use `data[x].price` instead of `data[i].price`. You have no `i`. Voting to close.

Comment: @veeeeetal, here's a small demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/8auy78cc. UPD: Oh sorry, I think I got your question partially wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accessing the values for each key. Try this:

```
for (const x of Object.keys(data)) {
    console.log(data[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was `data[x].price` instead of `data[i].price.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/data.json', function (data) {
    for (x in data) {
        console.log(data[x].price);  // First column
        console.log(data[x].quantity); // Second column
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- `data[i].price` should be `data[x].price`.
- `x["quantity"]` should be `data[i].quantity`.
- Create a `TABLE`, `TR` & `TD` element to display the values in a table.

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "Some name 1": {
        "price": 1023,
        "quantity": 93
    },
    "Some name 2": {
        "price": 2938,
        "quantity": 64
    },
    "Some name 3": {
        "price": 1277,
        "quantity": 211
    }
};

var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);
  
for (i in jsonObj) {

  var y = document.createElement("TR");
  y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
  document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);

  var x = document.createElement("TD");
  var nameNode = document.createTextNode(i);
  x.appendChild(nameNode);
  document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(x);

  var price = document.createElement("TD");
  var priceNode = document.createTextNode(jsonObj[i].price);
  price.appendChild(priceNode);
  document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(price);

  var quantity = document.createElement("TD");
  var quantityNode = document.createTextNode(jsonObj[i].quantity);
  quantity.appendChild(quantityNode);
  document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(quantity);
  
}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```